# r shiny - shiny app works well locally but it does not work on server. It gives me an error message

Tags: r, shiny

Once I uploaded the server.R, ui.R, and global.R files, it gave me these messages:

"An error has occurred"

"The application failed to start."

Here is my Github account containing the source codes:

https://github.com/ryuth/shiny-MLBpitchFX_velocity

I had this problem for a couple days and I am quite fed up. I even checked the log files by adding shinyapps::showLogs(). (I also added parameters accordingly to my accounts)

Here are my logs:

```
2015-07-30T20:59:59.390947+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: Starting R with process ID: '12'
2015-07-30T23:14:21.628231+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: R version: 3.2.1
2015-07-30T23:14:21.628283+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: shiny version: 0.12.1
2015-07-30T23:14:21.628285+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: rmarkdown version: 0.7
2015-07-30T23:14:21.628294+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: knitr version: 1.10.5
2015-07-30T23:14:21.628295+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: jsonlite version: 0.9.16
2015-07-30T23:14:21.628342+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: htmltools version: 0.2.6
2015-07-30T23:14:21.628623+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: Using jsonlite for JSON processing
2015-07-30T23:14:21.826908+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: 
2015-07-30T23:14:21.826913+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: Starting R with process ID: '12'
2015-07-30T23:14:21.628302+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: RJSONIO version: 1.3.0
2015-07-30T23:14:30.964879+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: R version: 3.2.1
2015-07-30T23:14:30.964960+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: shiny version: 0.12.1
2015-07-30T23:14:30.964961+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: rmarkdown version: 0.7
2015-07-30T23:14:30.964972+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: knitr version: 1.10.5
2015-07-30T23:14:30.964973+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: jsonlite version: 0.9.16
2015-07-30T23:14:30.964974+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: RJSONIO version: 1.3.0
2015-07-30T23:14:30.964998+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: htmltools version: 0.2.6
2015-07-30T23:14:30.965274+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: Using jsonlite for JSON processing
2015-07-30T23:14:31.161536+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: 
2015-07-30T23:14:31.161541+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: Starting R with process ID: '27'
2015-07-30T23:15:13.122164+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: R version: 3.2.1
2015-07-30T23:15:13.122235+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: shiny version: 0.12.1
2015-07-30T23:15:13.122237+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: rmarkdown version: 0.7
2015-07-30T23:15:13.122246+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: knitr version: 1.10.5
2015-07-30T23:15:13.122247+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: jsonlite version: 0.9.16
2015-07-30T23:15:13.122275+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: RJSONIO version: 1.3.0
2015-07-30T23:15:13.122300+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: htmltools version: 0.2.6
2015-07-30T23:15:13.122565+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: Using jsonlite for JSON processing
2015-07-30T23:15:13.309834+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: 
2015-07-30T23:15:13.309839+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: Starting R with process ID: '37'
2015-07-30T23:15:40.950061+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: R version: 3.2.1
2015-07-30T23:15:40.950116+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: shiny version: 0.12.1
2015-07-30T23:15:40.950117+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: rmarkdown version: 0.7
2015-07-30T23:15:40.950127+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: knitr version: 1.10.5
2015-07-30T23:15:40.950128+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: jsonlite version: 0.9.16
2015-07-30T23:15:40.950135+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: RJSONIO version: 1.3.0
2015-07-30T23:15:40.950178+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: htmltools version: 0.2.6
2015-07-30T23:15:40.950416+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: Using jsonlite for JSON processing
2015-07-30T23:15:41.137130+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: 
2015-07-30T23:15:41.137135+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: Starting R with process ID: '47'
2015-07-30T23:23:38.345286+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: R version: 3.2.1
2015-07-30T23:23:38.345345+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: shiny version: 0.12.1
2015-07-30T23:23:38.345347+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: rmarkdown version: 0.7
2015-07-30T23:23:38.345361+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: knitr version: 1.10.5
2015-07-30T23:23:38.345362+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: jsonlite version: 0.9.16
2015-07-30T23:23:38.345363+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: RJSONIO version: 1.3.0
2015-07-30T23:23:38.345391+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: htmltools version: 0.2.6
2015-07-30T23:23:38.345655+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: Using jsonlite for JSON processing
2015-07-30T23:23:38.570733+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: 
2015-07-30T23:23:38.570738+00:00 shinyapps[53094]: Starting R with process ID: '57'
```

I added all the libraries that I needed to the source code. What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: Maybe I am missing a library needed to runs this on server. I don't know what it is.

Comment: That is my guess too. No install.package in the github, so very well could just be missing it on the server.